# data system design

Tags: php, mysql

Need some ideas/help on best way to approach a new data system design. Basically, the way this will work is there will be a bunch of different database/tables that will need to be updated on a regular (daily/weekly/monthly) basis with new records.

The people that will be imputing the data will be proficient in excel. The input process will be done via a simple upload form. Then the system needs to add what was imported to the existing data in the databases. There needs to be a "rollback" process that'll reset the database to any day within the last week.

There will be approximatively 30 to 50 different data sources. the main primary interface will be an online search area area. so all of the records need to be indexed/searchable.

Ideas/thoughts on how to best approach this?  It needs to be built mostly out of php/mysql.

Comment: Which part of that do you need advice on? Putting data in a database from your form is straightforward -- generate and execute `INSERT` queries. Rolling it back to a date is also straightforward, `DELETE` all rows where the date you stored in some column is greater than the rollback date. Your question here is kinda like "I need help designing a car. It should be able to go up hill and down hill, and needs to be operated by proficient drivers." Great, now what advice would you give that guy?

Comment: It should have brakes. <-- legit advice about a car that needs to go up/down hills. But seriously. What Dan Grossman meant is you should bring this over to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> imputing the data

Typo?

What you are asking takes people with several years formal training to do. Conventionally, the approach would be to draw up a set of requirements, then a set of formal specifications, then the architecture of the system would be designed, then the data design, then the code implementation. There are other approaches which tend to shortcut this. However even in the case of a single table (although it does not necessarily follow that one "simple upload form" corresponds to one table), with a single developer there's a couple of days work before any part of the design could be finalised, the majority of which is finding out what the system is supposed to do. But you've given no indication of the usage nor data complexity of the system.

Also what do you mean by upload? That implies they'll be manipulating the data elsewhere and uploading files rather than inputting values directly.

You can't adequately describe the functionality of a complete system in a 9 line SO post.

You're unlikely to find people here to do your work for free.

You're not going to get the information you're asking for in a S.O. answer.

You seem to be struggling to use the right language to describe the facts you know.

Your question is very vague.